# How to get the pid of a process in Python

Tags: command-line, python

I wrote this script to stop processes:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='this script allows you to   connect a device in your network')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--mac', dest='mac', type=str, required=True, help='put mac of victim')
args = parser.parse_args()
mac_host =str(args.mac)
print "mac_host %s"%mac_host
p = subprocess.Popen("sudo kill -9 $(sudo ps aux|grep '(" + mac_host + ")'|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}')", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0].rstrip()
```

But I have a problem: the pid is always empty.

```
mac_host 14:KL:73:GH:45:7f

Usage:

    kill pid ... Send SIGTERM to every process listed.
    kill signal pid ... Send a signal to every process listed.
    kill -s signal pid ... Send a signal to every process listed.
    kill -l List all signal names.
    kill -L List all signal names in a nice table.
    kill -l signal Convert between signal numbers and names.
```

How can I solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should be a regular expression?

```
grep '(" + mac_host + ")'
```

Try with `egrep` or `grep -e`.

Looks like you want to use regular expressions but are looking for exactly the term you enter above. Or if it is called mac_host alle the time, then get rid of everything else

```
grep "mac_host"
```

Also put a

```
set +x
```

in your script to debug your script.

Cheers,
s1mmel

Answer (score 0):

Bleh can't comment still yet,

Above is correct, but if you use pgrep you have less to cleanup. It only returns the pid's (and not the entire line of ps).

```
p = subprocess.Popen("sudo kill -9 $(sudo ps aux| pgrep '(" + mac_host + ")')", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Edit:

If you want to try without using subprocess/shell commands, you could try something like this,

```
import os
from signal import SIGKILL


pids = [pid for pid in os.listdir('/proc') if pid.isdigit()]
for pid in pids:
    if mac_host in open(os.path.join('/proc', pid, 'cmdline'), 'rb').read():
        os.kill(int(pid), SIGKILL)
```

Might need regex if "if mac_host in" doesn't do it's job though.

Used sources:

[how-to-terminate-process-from-python-using-pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856928/how-to-terminate-process-from-python-using-pid)

[process-list-on-linux-via-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python)